# Horror short story anthology from either late 70s-80s with a ghoul/changeling

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

There was a horror short story collection I read as a child in the mid 80s. The story I remember was about a ghoul. This was a love story of sorts between a human girl and a changeling/ghoul boy. They grew up together as children, the girl would visit the boy at his home. As they grew up they drifted, mainly because of puberty I think. The boy always loved the girl and he didn't know what he was. The girl started dating douchebags. There was a scene where she gets raped by said douchebag and she just coldly stares at the guy. I think the ghoul ends up "saving" her by eating the douchebag. Something like this happened I can't remember fully. I'd really like to know who wrote this and the title...Thx

Comment: We have another question about boy meets ghoul at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107141/the-anthologys-name-and-title-of-a-short-story-where-two-ghouls-fall-in-love albeit the anthology is more recent and the sexes are swapped. Still, it might be worth looking at.

Comment: The story's plot sounds like "Shadetree", by Michael reeves, about a changeling boy (A hollow-eyed creature called a Haunt) told from the perspective of Shadetree's childhood friend Collly-Sue. I read the story in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, so I'm afraid I can't help with the title of the collection that you read.

Answer (score 4):

The story's plot sounds like "Shadetree", by Michael Reaves, about a changeling boy (A hollow-eyed ghoul called a Haunt) told from the perspective of Shadetree's childhood friend Collly-Sue. Shadetree never hides what he is, but the other children believe his stories to be nothing more than youthful fantasizing about a well-known local legend. As the characters mature, Shadetree urges Colly Sue to help him arrange for non-embalmed corpses to be buried in the local cemetery for the feeding of the other Haunts:

*“You got to tell your cousin
E.A. something important,” he
said. His voice was quiet and soft,
showing no signs of grief at all as he
squatted holding the man’s head.
“Tell him what?” Colly Sue decided that she would be damned if
she would show any more emotion
than Shadetree did. To prove she
was strong, she pinched the dead
eyes shut, but the head lolled at
such an angle that they fell open
again.
“You got to have him promise
that he won’t embalm Uncle Arlie.”
Shadetree released the corpse and
put his hands on Colly Sue’s
shoulders — his right thumb left a
spot of blood on the crisp white
cotton.
Her cousin was the local mortician. “Whatever for? E.A. could
go to jail for that!”
“It’s not against the law,”
Shadetree told her. “Say it was
Uncle Arlie’s last request.”
“That waren’t never no request
of his,” Colly Sue said slowly.
“It’s a request of mine,” Shadetree said. “That old man ain’t
gonna be embalmed.” He hesitated, then explained, “The haunts
need him, is why.”*

Shadetree later expresses an unusual regret after causing the violent death of Colly Sue's abusive husband:

*Shadetree stood beneath the shelter of a magnolia tree, staring at the pickup’s  blackened metal skeleton. She  stood beside him, numbly.  After a time he sighed, shook his  head and said sadly, “Hardly a bone left to bury. Ain’t that a god-damn shame."*

I read the story in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, so I'm afraid I can't help with the title of the collection that you read. My research says that the story was published in 1978, but I did read it earlier, no later than 1977.

Comment: I think you mean "Michael _Reaves_" per [this ISFDb entry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?973062).

Comment: Note that this is a reasonable match, but your recollection isn't perfect.  You might want to [re-read the story](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v053n03_1977-09_Lenny_Silv3r/page/n49/mode/2up) and insert a few quotes.